# How to change field value font styles in ServiceNow?

Tags: servicenow

Is it possible to change field value font styles on OnLoad in servicenow ? I was able to change field label styles using below code.

```
// Custom field label colors
    var stateLabel = g_form.getLabel('short_description');
    stateLabel.style.color= 'red';
    stateLabel.style.fontWeight='bold';
```

I tried to change field value font styles in similar way but no luck.

```
var stateValue = g_form.getValue('short_description');
    stateValue.style.color= 'red';
    stateValue.style.fontWeight='bold';
```

above code does not do any good , any thoughts on getting this to work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API call you're using `g_form.getValue(...)` is just going to return the string value of whatever field you're asking for.

To get access to the Element (like with `getLabel`) you can use `g_form.getControl(...)`

Example:

```
var el = g_form.getControl('short_description');
el.style.color = 'red';
el.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
```

However, I'd advise that instead of doing direct DOM manipulation with client-side javascript, that you use [Field Styles](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=Defining_Field_Styles) instead:

> Field styles allow administrators to declare individual CSS styles for
>   a field in a list or form. The CSS can:
>
> - Change the color.
> - Change the font attributes (bold, italics, underline).
> - Change the padding and alignment of text.

Field Styles allow you to specify a particular field, and apply arbitrary CSS. 
To take it a step further, it even allows you to specify javascript to conditionally apply the Style based on something like the state of the record.

Comment: Thanks i tested the JS way and its working and I am now going to study about Field Styles, Thanks for all recommendations :)

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to look at the VIP Callers on the Incident form, the field value color is sat to Red when the `Caller.VIP = True`

if this is your requirement, I would be happy to look it up for you.